# iOS 14 - I stopped receiving text notifications while I’m on a phone call. How do I get notifications back?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, text

iOS 14 - I stopped receiving text notifications while on a phone call. How do I get the text notifications back?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I was on a phone call, looking away from my phone, relying on text sound notifications to alert me. When the sound alert stopped, I missed a bunch of text messages. I think I found the fix. Settings>Sound and Haptics. Move the Ringer and Alerts slide from left (mute) to right so sound is allowed.[image]